# Cocos2d Using the same

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, repeat, sprite

I need to create the same sprite, with the same image, like 50 - 100 times. I read that initializing them all by themselves creates a performance issue, is there a command to do this? if `CCBatchNode` is what should be used then please explain how it works. and YES i have searched the internet for like an hour now. any info would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I believe that Cocos2d will only load the image from file once, and then cache the texture data for subsequent requests to the same file... but you might [consider using sprite sheets anyways](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d).

Comment: k im going with the spritesheets thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocos2d loads the texture in the memory only once and keeps on using it for texture needs. So no problems with creating 100 references with same texture. It won't affect memory much.